# Regex Match if present does not match a line

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a set of strings coming in as:

- Site: 4442.001 Rental Charge (x 1) PU094928
- Exchange1 x 6m Marrell - Construction &
- Emptying of bin1 x 240L - Commercial & PU094928

I want to match it into 3 columns if Site*** presents at the start and if P*** presents in the end
else match all of it

I am trying

```
^(.*)??(Site\S\s\d+\S\d+)?(.*)?\s(P.*?)$
```

But it is missing

- Exchange1 x 6m Marrell - Construction &

How can I do it?

Regex: PCRE(PHP<7.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the last part, including `\s` needs to be optional to match the string without it

try

```regex
^(Site\S\s\d+\S\d+)?(.*?)((\s)P.*)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/SuvUDb/1

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an optional non capture group to not capture the space and make the pattern a bit more specific:

```
^(Site:\h\d+\.\d+)?(.+?)(?:\h(P.*))?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(Site:\h\d+\.\d+)?` Optional **group 1**, match `Site:` a space and digits `.` digits
- `(.+?)` Capture **group 2**, match at last 1 or more times any char to not match an empty string
- `(?:\h(P.*))?` Optional non capture group, match a space and capture `P` and 0+ times any char in **group 3**
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NhztbS/1)